# How to get output of system command in case of error?

Tags: racket

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42126030) about this kind of thing I learned how to access the output of a command in case of success and to execute other code in case of error. However, usually it makes more sense for me to print the output of a command in case of error. The code that solved the other question was:

```
(with-output-to-string
  (lambda ()
    (unless (system "ls -la")
      ;; handle error here
      )))
```

How can I get the output of the system command inside the `unless` form?

Usage example: I want to run some system commands and only want to print "Success!" to terminal, if the command succeeded and in case of error I want to print "Error!" plus the actual output of the command.

Note: I do not want to run the command twice, because many system commands have side effects, which I do not want to trigger twice, just to get an output and the output of such a second call might be different from the first call anyway and thus might not reflect the actual error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure, [process](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._process%29%29), produces a list of five values, two of which are input ports (piped from the subprocess's stdout and stderr), and last is a procedure that can be used to get the exit-code of the subprocess. For example,

```
> (process "someCommand")
'(#<input-port:subprocess-stdout>
  #<output-port:subprocess-stdin>
  11292
  #<input-port:subprocess-stderr>
  #<procedure:control>)
```

To get the exit code of the subprocess, call on the last item (which is a procedure) with the argument `'exit-code`, as such:

```
((last (process "someCommand")) 'exit-code)
```

But note that the above procedure returns `#f` instead of an integer if subprocess is still running, so first call it with the argument `'wait`, and then call it with `'exit-code`. For example,

```
> (define cmd (process "someCommand"))
> ((last cmd) 'wait)
> ((last cmd) 'exit-code)   ; should now return an integer
```

Exit code can now be compared, and in the case that it is non-zero, `stderr` input port can be read and printed.

Below is a sample function that produces `"Success!"` if a subprocess executes successfully, and prints `"Error! + error-message"` in case of error:

```
(define (output command)
  (define cmd (process command))
  ((last cmd) 'wait)
  (define exit-code ((last cmd) 'exit-code))
  (if (= exit-code 0)
      "Success!"
      (printf "Error!\n~a\n" (read-line (fourth cmd)))))
```

For example;

```
> (output "date")
Success!
> (output "ls -al")
Success!
> (output "someCommand")
Error!
/bin/sh: 1: someCommand: not found
```

Comment: I noticed, that one can call `read-line` multiple times and it seems to be an iterator. I print all the lines. I would only need to compare against `#<eof>`. Is there a better way to print the complete output?

Comment: Using what is provided in this answer I created: https://gist.github.com/ZelphirKaltstahl/2d229948cf0486854bd9e1a17589189a

Comment: You can use [read-string](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Byte_and_String_Input.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read-string%29%29) instead of `read-line` to read multiple lines from an input port. For example, `(read-string 10000 (fourth cmd))` would read up to 10000 chars, or stop and return string if `eof` is encountered prior. You can change 10000 to a number that suits your needs.